# EF Core DbContext caching resulted included entities with dynamic Global filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am experiencing an issue with EF Core DbContext when using an ambient-based property called `RegistrationRoundId`, which can be changed by the `RegistrationRoundIdProvider` under ambient context. The `RegistrationRoundId` is used in a global query filter of the DbContext, and when I request a query with nested objects dependent on `RegistrationRoundId` and then change the ambient `RegistrationRoundId` using the `RegistrationRound` provider and request the same query, the resulted nested entities seem to get cached and associated with the new entities dependent on the new `RegistrationRoundId` value. I have tried declaring the `RegistrationRoundId` as a property of the DbContext and following EF Core conventions, but the problem persisted. However, I have noticed that the problem disappears in two scenarios: when I use the AsNoTracking() extension method and when I request the two queries in two different scopes, which I assume causes a new instance of DbContext to be created in every scope. Can someone explain why this issue occurs and how can solve this problem?
I wish to know if there is a professional suggestion rather than manual and repetitive workarounds

Here is a snippet of my code that shows the problem

```
 // here the parent context of the registration round id, says id1
      r = lst.Select(e => (object)new
    {
        e.Id,
        e.StudyYearId,
        countRequest = e.Requests.Count,
        // requests related to id1 will be present alone here
        requests = e.Requests.Select(e => e.RegistrationRoundId).ToList()
    })
        .FirstOrDefault();
// says id2
using (_currentRegistrationRound.Change(rs[1].Id))
        {

            r1 = (await qryM.ToListAsync())
        .Select(e => (object)new
        {
            e.Id,
            e.StudyYearId,
            countRequest = e.Requests.Count,
             //here the requests are related to id1 and id2
            requests = e.Requests.Select(e => e.RegistrationRoundId).ToList()
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();



        }
        // says id3
        using (_currentRegistrationRound.Change(Guid.NewGuid()))
        {

            r2 = (await qryM.ToListAsync())
      .Select(e => (object)new
      {
          e.Id,
          e.StudyYearId,
          countRequest = e.Requests.Count,
          // here the id3 has no related requests, however, id1 and id2 related requests 
          //are present !!
          requests = e.Requests.Select(e => e.RegistrationRoundId).ToList()
      })
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE**

I have used a simple dependent property in the DdContext:
`public Guid RegistrationRoundId {get; set;}`
and used to to examine the behavior which unfortunatilly shown same wrong results

see below image:

[image]

Comment: additionally, the log and sql server profiler is showing the SQL query compatible with the changes of registration round

Comment: Can you show your query filter? And explain why you have added `ToListAsync` before `Select`.

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question, I have used toListAsync and then used FirstOrDefault to have a simplified anonymous object to ease my investigation. 
I have also simplified the Query Filter and used RegistrationRoundId as a simple property in DBConext. however same result, the nested request is still cached

Comment: Only `AsNotracking` can help. EF Core will not remove from ChangeTracker entities which are already cached. Also if you remove ToListAsync before `Select` - it will also disable ChangeTracker.

Comment: So it should be a bug. As the query filter in nested properties is not applied on cached elements which will bring unrelated entities !

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is documented behavior or mentioned in docs. It is hard to find right words for searching. Also you can use `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` between queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I have noticed that the problem disappears in two scenarios: when I use the `AsNoTracking()` extension method and when I request the two queries in two different scopes, which I assume causes a new instance of `DbContext` to be created in every scope. Can someone explain why this issue occurs and how can solve this problem?

Well, you saw the cause of the problem - [tracking queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).

When you use tracking queries and resulting materialized entity instances (due to `ToList{Async}` calls), even though the global query filter is applied on database query, the results are consolidated into cached entity instances (client wins), rather than replacing them. Also no filtering is applied to already loaded entities. All this is due to EF Core navigation fixup, and also let not forget that we can manually add instances to these tracked collections, and again, no filtering will be applied.

Take a look at the following paragraph inside the [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) documentation, since both features use one and the same filtering subsystem (global query filters just add filters automatically, while in filtered includes they are specified manually):

> **Caution**
>
> In case of tracking queries, results of Filtered Include may be unexpected due to navigation fixup. All relevant entities that have been queried for previously and have been stored in the Change Tracker will be present in the results of Filtered Include query, even if they don't meet the requirements of the filter. Consider using `NoTracking` queries or re-create the `DbContext` when using Filtered Include in those situations.

As for a solution, as you can see, the docs suggest using `NoTracking` queries, so either add `AsNoTracking()` as you already did, or use projection (`Select`) query (directly on LINQ to Entities query source, without intermediate `ToList{Async}` and similar) which are the only ways you can get the exact data needed. There is no solution with EF Core tracking involved because the behavior is "by design", not a bug, and unlikely to change.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. After investigating the issue, I believe that it may be a bug in EF's caching strategy, rather than a documented limitation. The global query filter is designed to apply filters on the fly, including on nested properties. It appears to work correctly on the first query, but its behavior changes during the second query when it detects changes made to the active elements in the query and reflects those changes only in the SQL query itself. Note that this was happening without any explicit intervention in code !

Comment: I am currently writing an API code that follows the DDD design, which will be used by other developers. If we consider the issue to be a limitation, it can be challenging to make API users aware of it. There are no salient scenarios that could serve as a sign for developers to remember and adhere to the convention when coding.

Comment: I am considering a possible workaround for the issue, which involves implicitly detaching old nested elements when the filter changes, instead of consolidating them with the current cached elements. I plan to report this as a bug on Github and see if other developers have encountered similar problems.

Comment: @AbuDawood As I said, it is neither a bug nor limitation of the EF Core caching strategy. It is by design. There are only two possible strategies - client wins or server wins, and they choose this first.  You can report it as bug if you wish, but I'm almost 100% sure it will be closed as "by design".

Comment: In general, DDD principles are not their concern, because EF Core entities represent the **data** model, which is not the same as **domain** model. If you want to follow DDD principles, then require creating **separate** domain and data entity models and map between the two. When querying, the mapping means executing projection queries, i.e. no tracking, no data entities at all, full control of what is returned (global query filters still apply). That's it. You want EFC to follow your principles, but in fact you must follow their principles, which are the correct ones for the data model.

Comment: Speaking about workaround, instead of custom logic when filter changes (note that there is also `IgnoreQueryFilters()` at query level which you have no control over), consider just changing the default query tracking behavior, e.g. `dbContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution;`, even in the db context constructor. This way most of the queries will work the way you want, and  only the ones that really need tracking (for instance when applying disconnected updates) would explicitly use `AsTracking()`.